# How do I remove duplicate items from Lists after looping over them?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public static void FilterLockedThreads(List<string> Links, List<string> LockedLinks)
        {
            string number; 
            string number1;
            for (int i = 0; i < Links.Count; i++)
            {
                number = Links[i].Substring(32, 6);
                for (int x = 0; x < LockedLinks.Count; x++)
                {
                    number1 = LockedLinks[x].Substring(61, 6);
                    if (Links[i].Contains(LockedLinks[x]))
                    {

                        if (number == number1)
                        {
                            string identical = number;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I used a breakpoint and there are numbers that are part of an item in LockedLinks that also exist in Links.
Both Lists LockedLinks and Links are

For example in Links i have 50 items and in LockedLinks 7 items. For example in Links the item in index 32 is:

```
http://rotter.net/forum/scoops1/115156.shtml
```

And in LockedLinks in index 3 :

```
http://rotter.net/cgi-bin/forum/dcboard.cgi?az=read_count&om=115156&forum=scoops1
```

In both items there is the same number: 115156
Since this number exist in Links in index 32 and also in LockedLinks in index 3 then i want to remove this indexs from Links and LockedLinks.

In Links remove index 32 and in LockedLinks index 3.

I used substring to get the number from each List each itertion but it's never get inside never get to the string identical.

How can i make the comparison to work with the loops ? And how to make the remove of both indexs if identical ?

Comment: Side note: there are already plenty of classes/utilities that deal with url parsing: `Uri`, `Path` and [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx) - consider using them instead of substring.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Linq to remove duplicates:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

...

List<int> distinct = list.Distinct().ToList();
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-duplicates-list

Answer (score 0):

It's because this line:

```
if (Links[i].Contains(LockedLinks[x]))
```

is likely always evaluating to false. I'm not sure why you have that if statement.

Also to remove the items at those indexes you could keep a list if indexes for each array and add the value of `x` and `i` to each of them respectively when you find a match in the loop and then use those indexes to remove the items from each array after.

Answer (score 0):

in your example this line would prevent the number comparison:

```
if (Links[i].Contains(LockedLinks[x]))
{
```

I think you should simply remove it.

Answer (score 0):

First use more correct methods to get the numbers:

```
var num1 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("http://rotter.net/forum/scoops1/115156.shtml"); //return 115156
var num2 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(new Uri("http://rotter.net/cgi-bin/forum/dcboard.cgi?az=read_count&om=115156&forum=scoops1").Query)["om"]; //return 115156
```

Using these methods you can get two Lists, and then check for common numbers to remove them

```
var newList = list1nums.Except(list2nums).ToList();
```